# System.ArgumentException when calling g.DrawString() in Windows Forms .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm struggling a bit with an issue that I can't seem to figure out.

I have a simple Windows Forms application in which I'm displaying planets in our solar system and some information about them.

However, when I try to draw the planet details, I get the following exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
Additional information: Parameter is not valid.
```

This is the method in which I'm trying to do the drawing: (inside the main form class)

```
private void btnToggleInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    showPlanetDetails = !showPlanetDetails;

    if (showPlanetDetails)
    {
        foreach (var planet in planets)
        {
            var font = new Font("Times New Roman", 12);
            var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            g.DrawString(planet.ToString(), font, brush, planet.GetOccupiedScreenArea().Left, planet.GetOccupiedScreenArea().Bottom + 20);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the whole class: http://pastebin.com/55XtaRgT
Planet class: http://pastebin.com/iC7fgzqx

Any ideas why the application is failing? The error messages aren't very informative.

EDIT: Turns out the error occurs independently of the drawString method. I tried commenting out all drawing, and the same thing happened.

```
private void btnToggleInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    showPlanetDetails = !showPlanetDetails;

    if (showPlanetDetails)
    {
        foreach (var planet in planets)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from planet");
            //var font = new Font("Times New Roman", 12);
            //var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
           // g.DrawString(planet.Name, font, brush, planet.GetOccupiedScreenArea().Left,
             //   planet.GetOccupiedScreenArea().Bottom + 20);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: When I click the "show planet details"-button it also crashes with the same error: 
This is the only code for it:

```
private void btnToggleInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    showPlanetDetails = !showPlanetDetails;

    if (showPlanetDetails)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Button clicked");
    }
}
```

Comment: If the planet name is NEVER null, the problem could be happening in the Planet.Draw method. Could you paste the code for the Planet class as well?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've updated my question again, and it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the planet class. It crashes with the same error when I click a button that doesn't do anything with planets.

Comment: Yes but things could be misleading here. While you are getting the crash on the click, and thus think the problem may reside on the click handler, but the OnPaint() method may be getting called and crashing there.

Comment: Oh, that is indeed possible. Didn't think of that. Here's the planet class: http://pastebin.com/iC7fgzqx

Comment: I do not see anything wrong initially. We can try to do this in a trial-and-error approach. Try placing the code inside the Draw method of the Planet class inside a try...catch block, just to see if we can identify it as the culprit...

Comment: I really actually doubt that the `btnToggleInfo_Click` handler can fail with that error. I'm pretty sure that the `ArgumentNullException` can not occur in the last version of `btnToggleInfo_Click` you've provided (EDIT 2)

Comment: Didn't help. I do suspect that it has something to do with the graphics object though. Now the click method seems to run fine as long as I don't make a method call on the graphics object (g). Is it because the graphics object is declared as a member variable?

Comment: I cleaned the project, and the click handler no longer crashes. It only crashes when I call methods on the graphics object. I don't understand why though :S

Comment: Ok I think I know that the problem is..

Instead of drawing using the Planet.Draw method, try drawing the ellipse directly in the OnPaint method (so you don't pass the Graphics instance to another method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working. There was apparently a problem with having the Graphics object as a member variable and call it from my methods. I instead ended up doing:

```
var g = CreateGraphics();
g.drawString(...);
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It can happen if planet name is null.

Comment: I did a check on planet name now and it's never null

Comment: Turns out the error occurs even if I don't use the drawString method. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

then you have some values in your list planet  is null, uou can test this Methode

```
  foreach (var planet in planets.Where(planet => planet != null))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from planet");
        //var font = new Font("Times New Roman", 12);
        //var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
       // g.DrawString(planet.Name, font, brush, planet.GetOccupiedScreenArea().Left,
         //   planet.GetOccupiedScreenArea().Bottom + 20);
    }
```